# SSL Setup for SaaS Application with Custom Domain Names

Tags: ssl, dns, saas

I am developing a SaaS web application (`https://mywebsite.example`) which will be hosted in AWS and will have subdomains for individual customers like `https://customer1.mywebsite.example` , `https://customer2.mywebsite.example`.

As a second step I would like to introduce custom domain names and map it with the subdomains of mywebsite.com through cname records

- `https://customer1.example` --> `https://customer1.mywebsite.example`

Here is what I have analysed till now.

1. Using Certificates in AWS loadbalancer for the custom domains as a SAN in the certificate. However the AWS Loadbalancer certificate limits are lesser than the number of customers I am expecting to add.
2. CloudFlare DNS setup for `mywebsite.example` and its subdomains, with ssl certificates configured in cloudflare. However Cloudflare allows thirdparty (custom domain) cname redirections only in the Enterprise Plan.

Are there any other alternative service or are there is an alternate way of achieving this use case?

Comment: Are you asking for a wildcard SSL certificate?

Comment: I think SANs are the only way to do this? unless you want to deploy separate certificate for each domain.

Comment: @Yuvaraj ,Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this solution available in AWS EC2 marketplace should solve your problem
You can try, there is some trial available, called Kilo SSL

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-nedlvgpke4hdk?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

Also it is possible to map your customer's domains to your saas. Algorithm is:

1. you create EC2 instance. Allocate and associate public IP to it
2. create domain name which points to this instance. You will use this domain name as CNAME when pointing your own subdomains in your DNS provider (but there is limit of 50 certificates per week per one domain, so you can create only 50 domains like customer1.yourdomain.com ... customer50.yourdomain.com per week)
3. For customers who want to use their own domains (like app.customer1.com), you also provide them your CNAME and ask customer to set DNS record. After they will do it, you will be able to create certificate for their domain using this service.

Also this service allows to point different domains to different URLs. We started to use this in our SAAS application for URL shortening (we have several hundreds of customers who use their own domains. So we automatically able to create certificate for them, and everything is automated via API). Also we use the same machine to support SSL for all our company's domains.

available API methods: https://docs.kilossl.com/